# dropdownlist error in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Hi I'm a Dot Net Developer and I'm new to PHP also using Laravel framework
I have a problem in my dropdownlist, I already did populating the data from database to a dropdownlist but when I'm saving the data the dropdownlist id does not added in the database I just got NULL value.

This is my Controller

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
    'title' => 'required',
    'description' => 'required'
    ]);

    $input = $request->all();

    Task::create($input);

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Task successfully added!');
    return redirect()->back();
}

public function create()
{
     $category = Category::lists('Category', 'Id'); 
     return View('tasks.create')->with('category', $category);
}
```

And this in my View

```
<div class="form-group"> 
{!! Form::label('cagetory_id', 'Category:', ['class' => 'control-label']) !!} 
{!! Form::select('cagetory_id', $category, null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
</div>
```

I'm using Laravel 5, Thank you in advance to those who can help me :)

Answer (score 0):

Check you Eloquent Model, if you added the 'category_id' to the mass assignment ($fillable) list.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Flight extends Model
{
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = ['name'];
}
```

Comment: I already added that

This is my Model

    protected $fillable = [
        'title',
        'description',
        'category_id'       
    ];

Still doesn't work :(

Comment: I already found the answer, I just change the $category to $category->toArray to return array not a collection, and it works fine :)